# Entity Converting all DateTimes to Jan 1

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I'm using Entity to pull some data from a customer's SQL table and I want to filter it based on date. The customer stored the relevant month of each row as a 6-digit string in the YYYYMM format. My attempt to resolve this (because I can't change the column type to a datetime2) has been to create a SQL View that does the following to create a datetime2 column representing the month:

```
CONVERT(datetime2, MON.Month + '01') AS CoveredMonth
```

Then inside of .NET, I have two DateTime objects, yearStart and yearEnd, that represent January 1st, 2016 and January 1st, 2017, as well as the specific employee whose records I'm looking for. I have the following code to attempt to filter on this column:

```
 IList<MonthlyRecord> monthlyRecords = m_LTContext.MonthlyRecords
     .Where(r => r.EmployeeID == employee.ID && r.CoveredMonth >= yearStart && r.CoveredMonth < yearEnd)
     .ToList<MonthlyRecord>();
```

When I place a break point to check what is returned to `monthlyRecords` I see the expected *count* of records. However, each record has a `CoveredMonth` set to January 1st, 2016. Running the same query in SQL I get an identical *count* of records again, but the appropriate dates: Jan 1 '16, Feb 1 '16, etc.

Is there an issue with Entity somehow mapping properties that are non-standard on a View? There a few hacks I have in my mind but I'd really like to resolve this "properly".

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - the View was using the EmployeeID as the primary key and not the MonthlyRecordID.